# Installing head plugin in elastic search with Grails

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-2.0

I have Grails project in which I have added elastic search dependencies. 
Now I want to install [head plugin](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) .

According to documentation of head plugin, command for this is:

`elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head`

But I am not able to find bin directory of ES.

So where is the elasticsearch installed in Grails ?

Answer (score 2):

Do :

```
cd /usr/share
```

and

```
elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a Car with Satellite radio in it. If there is a request to add a new channel to the satellite radio service, then that has to be done in the broadcasting station instead of installing any kind of component/tool in your Car. :)

Similarly, When you say you added elastic search dependencies to a Grails project that does not mean you have a elastic **server** running in the same application.

The documentation for head plugin (here plugin means an add-on to elastic server, instead of a Grails plugin) refers to elastic server (where you can find a `bin` directory).

Your best approach would be [Running as a standalone webapp](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/) if you have elastic server running in your localhost during development. Or run it as a plugin to elastic server installation wherever it is installed. I hope I was able to convey. :)

Comment: Correct. I have @PostConstruct in one of my service class & in that I am starting one node of ES cluster. So this starts my ES server at localhost:9200. That means grails itself is starting that service. Now if grail is having an access to that batch file (elasticsearch.bat), then ElasticSearch is installed in some directory by Grials. So if I can get the location of that installed ElasticSearch's bin folder, I can install head plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
cd /usr/share
```

and

```
elasticsearch/bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```